# Parse simple JSON in Android 4.4 from URL

Tags: java, android, json, android-json

I am trying to parse very simple JSON in Android 4.4 from an URL that looks like this:

```
{
    "code":"asdfg"
}
```

I have a working code for Android 7.0, but for some reason it doesn't work in Android 4.4, and I have not have any luck with guides online.

Any help is appreciated :)

EDIT - current code (Works on Android 7 but not on Android 4.4):

```
static class Page {
String code;
}

public static String checkIp() throws Exception {
String json = readUrl("https://link.com/json.php");  //Not the real URL, replaced as an example
Gson gson = new Gson();
Page page = gson.fromJson(json, Page.class);
Log.d("MainActivity", page.code);
return (page.code);
}

private static String readUrl(String urlString) throws Exception {
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    int read;
    char[] chars = new char[1024];
    while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
        buffer.append(chars, 0, read);

    return buffer.toString();
} finally {
    if (reader != null)
        reader.close();
}
}
```

It gives me an error on these lines:

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
```

The error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb8ca3c40: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:146)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
W/System.err:     at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
```

Comment: show you code..

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: @prem Sorry about that. Edited my question

Comment: @ankitpatidar Sorry about that. Edited my question

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: @diegoveloper It just says this: `W/System.err: at com.a.b.c.MainActivity.readUrl(MainActivity.java:244)` and the other part is on my question

Comment: @FrankFabregat3 link is not working correctly. There is 404 error on page

Comment: @Prem The link was replaced by that because the actual one is personal

Comment: @FrankFabregat3 the destination host doesnt have a proper signed certificate. Either add the host certificate to your device or get a proper certificate from issuing authority like Godaddy or switch to http for testing puprpose

Comment: @gvmani Could you post your answer as an actual answer to give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, check the url is it working correctly. Sometimes it happens that link is not working. and check properly for **HTTPS or HTTP because calling for https of http link(vise-versa) may rise this error.** because of the handshake problem arise mostly.

calling of method "checkIp()" need to be from background thread as.

```
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    String s = checkIp();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

There is nothing wrong in code just except "thread" problem.

I think this may solve your problem. I check at my end it working for normal link.

Let me know if not working else.

Comment: So I was playing around with my code and on both Android 7 and 4.4 gave an error about HTTP 301 moved temporarily when calling the URL with `http://`. When calling the URL with `https://` worked perfectly on Android 7 but gave an error on Andriod 4.4 `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb8cb3c40: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer`

Comment: its because, there are two type of SSL certificate i.e v1.1 and v1.2 for webservice creation:: previously before 5.0 it only support which ever they would be either http or https. But due to confortability by Android from 5.0 it will support both the certificate what ever it was, it will work.

Comment: on the `checkIp()` function, on Android 7 using `http`, `readUrl()` returns the HTTP 301 moved temporarily thing, and using `https` returns the actual JSON. On Android 4.4 using `http`, `readUrl()` returns the HTTP 301 moved temporarily thing, and using `https` returns `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb8d7a180: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer`

Comment: I got your problem actually, your link is http(by core) when you try to run on 7.0 with http it cant allow to execute http. and when you try to run https it allow as per new functionality (and certificates are allowed on 7.0 whatever it is, it will work), and now when you run http on 4.4 it gives error for redirection of link to https and when you try to run by https it give error of SSL certificate(as it only allow whatever it was).

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening

Comment: Please upVote, if satisfy your question.

Comment: Done. Since I dont have much reputation, it doesn't display publicly, but it is recorded

Answer (score 0):

The destination host doesn't have a proper signed certificate. Either add the host certificate to your device or get a proper certificate from issuing authority like GoDaddy or switch to http for testing purpose

Comment: i just realized that changing it to `http://` kinda worked, but now it is telling me about `HTTP 301 moved temporarily`. Do you know what this means?

Comment: is your sever configured to accept http? maybe its configured to redirect http traffic to https

Comment: Yes it redirects it to https

Comment: in that case,  you wont be able to use http. You can try adding your host certificate to your device https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2844832?hl=en
You will need to get a  certificate signed by recognized CA for this to work seamlessly